# Last character fails to show on rounded inputfield in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Has anyone seen this strange behaviour before?
When I have an input field in IE9, with a fixed width, some padding and rounded corners, for some reason the last character that I type when the textbox is full does not show up. It is there, but IE does not move the string enough to the left to show the rightmost character.

Here's a case to show what I mean.
The first field is ok, the second field shows the behaviour I explained when you continue to type when the field is already filled up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Text input field</title>
<style type="text/css">
.textItem {
    padding: 2px 8px 2px 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="padding: 50px 200px">

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" size="5"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <input class="textItem" style="width: 119px" type="TEXT"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this (hopefully without changing the css properties already defined)?

Comment: is it ok if you decrease `padding-right` lets say to `6px` or `7px`?

Comment: Not reproduceable. You are setting right padding to 8px, and that’s what happens.

Comment: Setting the padding to 2px all around indeed removes the problem, but it also reduces the width of my field (not wanted). And as for "not reproducable", no matter what styling you give, a letter typed should be visible. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by applying `box-sizing: border-box` to the input field.
I have adjusted the width accordingly.